# What is the purpose this code in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This the class--

```
class CategoriesModel{
  String imgUrl;
  String categoriesName;
}
```

This the function--

```
List<CategoriesModel> getCategories(){
 List<CategoriesModel> categories = new List();
 CategoriesModel categoriesModel = new CategoriesModel();

 //
 categoriesModel.imgUrl ="";
 categoriesModel.categoriesName = "";
 categories.add(categoriesModel);
 categoriesModel=new CategoriesModel();

 return categories;
}
```

I did not get this code 
please explain this in a simple way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to have more context about why do you need/use this function.

It is simply returning a list of `CategoriesModel` with a single object and empty.

`categoriesModel.imgUrl ="";
 categoriesModel.categoriesName = "";
 categories.add(categoriesModel);`

this new object does not makes much sense:

`categoriesModel=new CategoriesModel();`

Comment: Thank you I think I get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CategoriesModel{
  String imgUrl;
  String categoriesName;
}
```

You have a class with two properties of type String

---

```
List<CategoriesModel> getCategories(){
 List<CategoriesModel> categories = new List();
 CategoriesModel categoriesModel = new CategoriesModel();

 //
 categoriesModel.imgUrl ="";
 categoriesModel.categoriesName = "";
 categories.add(categoriesModel);
 categoriesModel=new CategoriesModel();

 return categories;
}
```

A function, you create a new list and then create a new instance of the class `CategoeriesModel()`. Then you set the value of `imgUrl` and `categoriesName` to empty `String` and add them to a list. For some reason you create another instance of `CategoeriesModel()`, and return the list with the values.